# How can a developer test apps on older versions of iOS

Tags: testing, ios4

I have an [app](http://www.bowleggedturtle.com/products/fitbeat) I've developed for iOS. It's been tested against iOS 5 and now I'd like to catch some 4.3 customers too. However, I've struggled to find any way to download v4.3 to my devices for testing. I would have assumed Apple would provide these to developers for this purpose, but I can't find any mention of old releases in the dev portal. What's the recommended way to approach this?

BTW, this app uses several hardware features of the iPhone and iPod Touch, so the simulator isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

In you case, I would by an old iphone/ipod, which is not that expensive (maybe $50) like the 3G and will restore it using it itunes and the seeds for iOS 4.3. If you can do that, finding the seeds, is not hard.

In this page you will find a direct link to apple's website to download the ipsw's.

http://techie-buzz.com/mobile-news/ios-4-3-ipsw-direct-download-links.html

Hope that helps! It's not hard! I have done it several times and it took me about 15 mins.

Answer (score -1):

You can't downgrade legally your devices, you might need another device or a use jailbroken one. Don't try to read the TOS of apple, your mind might explode of incomprehension. With iTunes and a little trick you can downgrade, but well, it's up to you.